# Mongodb/Mongoose Schemas for Enterprise, Enterprise User and User

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build an app that has enterprises, enterprise users and users. I have come up with these schemas/models.

```
var enterpriseSchema = new Schema({
    enterpriseId            :    ObjectId,
    enterpriseName          :    {type: String, index: true},
    enterpriseUsers         :    [enterpriseUserSchema],
    owner                   :    {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

var enterpriseUserSchema = new Schema({
    user                    :    {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    role                    :    {type: String, index: true},
    lastAccess              :    Date
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
    userId                  :    ObjectId,
    givenName               :    String,
    middleName              :    String,
    familyName              :    String,
    username                :    { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
    password                :    String,
    enterprise              :    {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Enterprise'}
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Enterprise = mongoose.model('Enterprise', enterpriseSchema);
```

Note the enterpriseUsersSchema. This seems like a reasonable way to reference enterprise users. Is it, or is there a better way?

If I use these schemas/models, how would I go about populating the users of an enterprise? I would need givenName, familyName and role for each user. I have tried populate but I can't determine how to populate users given the enterpriseUsersSchema.

Comment: Not sure you need two independent schemas, enterpriseUserSchema and userSchema cause it appears to be essentially a one to one mapping, unless there's another schema for roles. If enterpriseUserSchema is the rolesSchema, then user should be an array of userId's. To populate the users of an enterprise, consider using  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I tried to simplify my models. Ultimately, I'll need to support a one to many relationship between users and enterprises. I'm not sure what you had in mind for roles. I need to associate users with enterprises and I need to know what roles users have. Maybe I should just link the enterpriseUsersSchema into the enterpriseSchema. I may need to be able to send all users with the role of owner notifications. Thanks for your insights.